# How can I compute a rectangles outline using a unit square in the vertex shader?

Tags: shader, matrix

I'm trying to draw the outline of a rectangle (8 x vertices, 24 x indices, counterclockwise winding) using a unit rectangle and normals, with the model matrix scaling the outline thickness in the vertex shader. However, I'm only getting the bottom right hand half of the outline:

[image: Bottom right outline]

```
@vertex
fn vs_main(vertex: Vertex) -> VsOut {
    let ty = r_pc.info.x;
    let thickness = r_pc.info.y;
    let is_fill = select(false, true, ty >= 0.5 && ty < 1.5);
    let is_outline = select(false, true, ty >= 1.5 && ty < 2.5);

    var model = r_pc.model;
    var position = vec4(vertex.position, 0.0, 1.0);
    if is_outline {
        // Add thickness to model's scale components.
        var width = vertex.normal * thickness;
        model[0][0] += width.x;
        model[1][1] += width.y;
    }
    position = r_camera.view_proj * model * position;

    let color = r_pc.color;

    let uv = vertex.uv;

    return VsOut(position, color, uv);
}
```

If I instead add the normal to the outside corner vertices and scale by the thickness (10px), it's also wildly wrong!

[image]

```
@vertex
fn vs_main(vertex: Vertex) -> VsOut {
    let ty = r_pc.info.x;
    let thickness = r_pc.info.y;
    let is_fill = select(false, true, ty >= 0.5 && ty < 1.5);
    let is_outline = select(false, true, ty >= 1.5 && ty < 2.5);

    var model = r_pc.model;
    var position = vec4(vertex.position, 0.0, 1.0);
    if is_outline && vertex.id % 2 == 1 {
        // Add thickness to model's scale components.
        position += vec4(vertex.normal, 0.0, 0.0);
        var width = vertex.normal * thickness;
        model[0][0] += thickness;
        model[1][1] += thickness;
    }
    position = r_camera.view_proj * model * position;

    let color = r_pc.color;

    let uv = vertex.uv;

    return VsOut(position, color, uv);
}
```

Here are my geometry info:

```
[
Vertex { position: [0.0,0.0], normal: [0.0,0.0] },
Vertex { position: [0.0,0.0], normal: [-0.70710677,-0.70710677] },
Vertex { position: [0.0,1.0], normal: [0.0,0.0] },
Vertex { position: [0.0,1.0], normal: [-0.70710677,0.70710677] },
Vertex { position: [1.0,1.0], normal: [0.0,0.0] },
Vertex { position: [1.0,1.0], normal: [0.70710677,0.70710677] },
Vertex { position: [1.0,0.0], normal: [0.0,0.0], },
Vertex { position: [1.0,0.0], normal: [0.70710677,-0.70710677] },
]

indices => [
    0,1,2,
    2,1,3,
    2,3,4,
    4,3,5,
    4,5,6,
    6,5,7,
    6,7,0,
    0,7,1
]
```

The idea was to add the normals to the vertices and scale by the thickness. But as can be seen, the 2 approaches I had for doing this do not work.

The rectangle on its own should look like this:

[image: What it should look like]

How can I compute the outline of a rectangle in the vertex shader using a unit square combined with normals and an outline thickness?

**Edit:**

I'm a bit closer, having changed the shader code as follows, so that the axis normals are rotated into the correct coordinate space. These normals are then used to compute the offset and added to the inner position.

```
let world_position = model * vec4(vertex.position, 0.0, 1.0);
let x = normalize(model * vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0));
let y = normalize(model * vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0));
let offset = (x * vertex.normal.x + y * vertex.normal.y) * thickness;
let position = r_camera.view_proj * (world_position + offset);
```

However, that is not quite correct because the top left segment is 1px less than the bottom right:

[image: Almost there, missing 1px]

Comment: Can you add an image how it should look like?